# MongoDB and similar database technologies

Tags: mongodb

What are comparable database like Mongo DB?
We are trying to evaluate Mongo DB and find the best database for a enterprise level application.

Is there any developer UI and admin UI available for MongoDB like SQL Plus/Toad etc for Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is what is known as a NoSQL database, which is I assume why you're interested in it.  You can find a list of other NoSQL databases at the below links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

http://nosql-database.org/

MongoDB does not include a GUI-style administrative interface; however, there are numerous community projects that provide admin UIs for MongoDB:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

Answer (score 3):

[MongoDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is a [document-oriented database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database), so instead of a row of data, you have a document. In MonogDB's case, its a JSON document. Apache's [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is another document database that stores data in JSON format although there are subtle differences between the two.

Choosing between the two depends on your use case. Sometimes CouchDB is better than MongoDB.
Checkout [this comparative](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB) to see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I like document oriented databases like MongoDB very much. Because they are shema-less. You can just insert find and update your records without first having to define a schema. But you can define one in your own Project logic. You have more freedom.

It would be nice to have an embeddable NoSQL database. Like SQLite but document oriented.
Currently I do develop one in Java. (You can also use it withhin an Android App):

https://github.com/neo-expert/thingdb

Answer (score -1):

I am quite happy with [MongoVue](http://www.mongovue.com/tutorials/).  I've made a couple of videos about this [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCE5902FB1D284880&feature=view_all).